# How to count number of rows per distinct row in Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, count

I have a file like this:

```
id|domain
9930|googspf.biz
9930|googspf.biz
9930|googspf.biz
9931|googspf.biz
9931|googspf.biz
9931|googspf.biz
9931|googspf.biz
9931|googspf.biz
9942|googspf.biz
```

And I would like to count the number of times a distinct id shows up in my data like below:

```
9930|3
9931|5
9942|1
```

How can I do that with linux bash? Currently I am using this, but I am counting all lines with this:

```
cat filename | grep 'googspf.biz'| sort -t'|' -k1,1 | wc
```

can any body help?

Comment: Note that you should use directly `grep 'googspf.biz' filename` instead of using cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
awk -F'|' '
    /googspf.biz/{a[$1]++}
    END{for (i in a) {print i, a[i]}}
' OFS='|' file
```

or

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
    /googspf.biz/{a[$1]++}
    END{for (i in a) {print i, a[i]}}
' file
```

Comment: Also, from OPs code it looks like he may want some kind of filtering, so `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} /googspf.biz/ {a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) {print i, a[i]}}' file` can suit better.

Comment: No need for `NR>1` anymore with the `/googspf\.biz/` filtering.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 1d file | cut -d'|' -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 1):

I first thought of using `uniq -c` (`-c` is for count) since your data seems to be sorted:

```
~$ grep "googspf.biz" f | cut -d'|' -f1|uniq -c
      3 9930
      5 9931
      1 9942
```

And in order to format accordingly, I had to use awk:

```
~$ grep "googspf.biz" f | cut -d'|' -f1|uniq -c|awk '{print $2"|"$1}'
9930|3
9931|5
9942|1
```

But then, with awk only:

```
~$ awk -F'|' '/googspf/{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a){print i"|"a[i]}}' f
9930|3
9931|5
9942|1
```

`-F'|'` to use `|` as a delimiter, and if line matches `googspf` (or `NR>1`: if line's number is >1) increments the counter for the first field. At the end print accordingly.

Comment: Another way of doing the awk `awk -F'|' '{a[$/googspf/]++}END{for(i in a)print i FS a[i]}'`